# PHP PDO increment

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have to 2 questions:
 1.My problem is that when I try to increment the value is reset back to 1 ;
 2.Can I reduce my code to a MYSQL statement (the switch ... case code)

```
public static function process($nr,$id) // (x,y,z,a,b ?) (the column id)
{

$х=$y=$z=$a=$b=0;

  switch ($nr) {
    case '1':
        $х=1;
        break;

        case '2':
        $y=1;
        break;

        case '3':
        $z=1;
        break;

        case '4':
        $a=1;
        break;

        case '5':
        $b=1;
        break;

  }




$conn = new PDO( DBN, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
$sql = "UPDATE test_table SET b=+:b, a=+:a,z=+:z,y=+:y,х=+:х WHERE id = :id";
$st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
$st->bindValue( ":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st->bindValue( ":х", $х, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st->bindValue( ":y", $y, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st->bindValue( ":z", $z, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st->bindValue( ":a", $a, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st->bindValue( ":b", $b, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st->execute();
$conn = null;
print_r($st->errorInfo());
```

}

Comment: Why not do your increments in the PHP code rather than the query?

Comment: i dont think mySQL supports +=, try `b=b+:b` etc for the increments.

Comment: i'm trying to increment in mydatabase the row with specified id and the column x,y,z,a or b

Comment: MySQL has a `switch` equivalent called `CASE`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.htm.

Comment: Well it seems that mysql dosen't support '+=' ty gbtimmon.Any chance to reduce my php code to a mysql statement?

Comment: @user1612293 You can do it entirely in MySQL with the `IF()` function or with some `CASE` statements but it's messy. To me this looks like a flawed table design, it looks like you are storing some form of status across several fields, and you should be storing it in one. Can you expand on the real-world use case for this?

Comment: @user1612293 you can only ask one question at a time on here.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = column_name+1 WHERE id = ?;
```

Is the best way to increment any database counter because it is handled atomically which means no other process/thread can accidentally insert a previously read value, you are 100% sure that the value will be incremented by every call to the function/procedure.

If you do it in PHP another --you're gonna have a bad time-- because of classical race conditions:

```
user1 -> read value // value=10
user2 -> read value // value=10
user1 -> write value++ // value becomes 11
user2 -> write value++ // value (AGAIN) becomes 11 but it should've been 12
```

Avoiding this for more complicated queries involves using transactions and specific isolation levels. But as it so happens all SQL queries formed by a single statement are atomic.

Comment: can you step through the PDO code to answer the question, like you're writing one?

Comment: @IGotRoot I don't understand your question can you rephrase please?

Comment: Look at these examples: http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Prepared-Statement-P550.html and write out a sample increment pdo based upon it.

Comment: @IGotRoot I know how PDO works. I've been using it for years. I didn't write this answer using PDO because the problem is not related to PDO at all it's only related to how MySQL works.

Comment: Can you write it out like that in your answer, because I've tried getting it to work, and it just seems to fail when I do it on my own that way?

Answer (score -2):

why not ?

```
public static function process($nr,$id) // (x,y,z,a,b ?) (the column id)
{
$param;
switch ($nr) {
    case '1':
        $param = "x=x+1";
        break;

    case '2':
        $param = "y=y+1";
        break;

    case '3':
        $param = "z=z+1";
        break;

    case '4':
        $param = "a=a+1";
        break;

    case '5':
        $param = "b=b+1";
        break;

}

$conn = new PDO( DBN, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
$sql = "UPDATE test_table SET $param WHERE id = :id";
$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$st->bindValue( ":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$conn = null;
print_r($st->errorInfo());
```

Also here is an all my SQL solution, I bit more unweildy if you ask me though:

```
public static function process($nr,$id) // (x,y,z,a,b ?) (the column id)
{
    $sql <<<'EOD'
        UPDATE test_table SET
            x = CASE WHEN :nr = 1 THEN x + 1 ELSE x END CASE,
            y = CASE WHEN :nr = 2 THEN y + 1 ELSE y END CASE,
            z = CASE WHEN :nr = 3 THEN z + 1 ELSE z END CASE,
            a = CASE WHEN :nr = 4 THEN a + 1 ELSE a END CASE,
            b = CASE WHEN :nr = 5 THEN b + 1 ELSE b END CASE
        WHERE id = :id
     EOD;

     $conn = new PDO( DBN, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
     $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
     $st->bindValue( ":nr", $nr, PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $st->bindValue( ":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $conn = null;
     print_r($st->errorInfo());
}
```

Comment: Thats not a place holder, that is a php parameter. and an iterpolated string before the prepared statement is even created. Please read closer before you critcize. Edit -- Ill remove the prepared statemnet entirly for people this might 'confuse', since its unessacry here.

Comment: OK fair enough you are right I did misread it - and I didn't downvote - but it seems like the OPs approach to this problem is wrong if you look at the operation that is being performed, it seems like this is several fields where one will do.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for answers something like this I wanted!Thanks again